# a function pointer does not pass to react function via props

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I do not understand why xxx passes correctly, but func1 does not.
Looks like passing a function pointer to a function via props fails!???

```js
const {useState} = React;

function DragAndDropArena(props) {
//const DragAndDropArena = (props) => {
  const [func1] = useState(props.func1);
  const [func2] = useState(props.func2);
  const [xxx] = useState(props.xxx);
 
  console.log(props.func1); // looks fine
  console.log(xxx);   // xxx is 123 as expected
  console.log(func1); //  func1 is undefined !!!!!!!!!!
  console.log(func2); //  func2 is undefined !!!!!!!!!!
 
  return <div>AA</div>
}


class App extends React.Component {
  func1 = () => {} 
  func2() {} 
  render() {
     return (
       <DragAndDropArena
         func1={this.func1} 
         func2={this.func2} 
         xxx='123'
       />
     )
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React binding this to a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297676/react-binding-this-to-a-class-method)  Also, check the docs on useSelector to see how to properly desctructure it.

Comment: no. it does not work with binding as well

Comment: Please update your question with the properly bound functions that are still not working.  Maybe some mistake in how you're binding?  Overall, you don't need to write class components any more, btw.  Doing this all functionally will be easier.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its unrelated to binding, as the console.log(props.func1); prints the function just right

Comment: @jmargolisvt What about this behavior makes you think its related to binding or `useSelector`?

Answer (score 3):

[`React.useState()`](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#basic-hooks) has two signatures (see "Lazy initial state" in the linked documentation):

```
[getter, setter] = useState(defaultValue)
[getter, setter] = useState(defaultValueFunction)
```

If you pass any function to `useState`, it will call it and use the value as the default state value. You're passing functions which return `undefined`...

Comment: To fix, wrap it in another function `useState(() => props.func1)` that returns the function you want to set to state.

Comment: If there is any reason to fork those props to state in any case, yeah, that'd fix it.

Comment: I can't think of a possible reason you'd need to. But that is how you'd do it. Seems like the antipattern more common in classes of dumping props into state for no reason.

Comment: @BrianThompson YES! Thanks!

Comment: @DuduArbel But please also tell us why you're doing that for the props? You generally don't need to.

Comment: @AKX well, I want DragAndDropArena to be able to call a callback in App, and change it's state

Comment: @DuduArbel You don't need to put the function in state for that to work. Just call it from props `props.func1()`. State is for values that change over time. I won't say never, but functions rarely change after initialization, and I'd be interested to hear the use-case where a function changes throughout the lifecycle of a component and needs to be in state.

Comment: @DuduArbel Yeah, you'd just call it from `props` then.