# Can not access this.state.value from some function component of my class component

Tags: reactjs

When I am trying to access `removeperson` or `renamefun` within the class its working but when I am trying to access them from  some other function component it is giving error  `Cannot read property 'persons' of undefined`

### **1. Below is the code of my class component**

```
import './App.css';

import { Component } from 'react';
import Allpersons from '../Components/Allpersons/Allpersons';
import Person from '../Components/Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  state ={
   persons :  [
      {id:'ha1f' ,name :'harsh' , age : 25} ,
      {id: 'jak2' ,name :'mohit', age: 23} ,
      {id:'adsf23',name :'sachin' , age: 29}
    ],
    c:0 ,

    personview: false

  }

  




  togglepersonview=()=>{
   const val=this.state.personview;
   this.setState({personview:!val});
   

 }


 removeperson(index)
 {
   
   const people=[...this.state.persons];
   people.splice(index,1);
   this.setState({persons:people})
 }


renamefun(event,id){

const personindex=this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
 
  return p.id===id;  //will store values of only person which has id equal to id;
});
const personvalues={
  ...this.state.persons[personindex]
};
personvalues.name=event.target.value;

const people=[...this.state.persons];

people[personindex]=personvalues;
this.setState({persons :people});

}



  

  render(){

    const style={
      padding :'4px 6px' ,
      color:'white',
      backgroundColor:'green',
      border:'1px solid grey'
    }

    var showperson=null;

    if(this.state.personview){
      showperson=(

        <div>
        
                  
   
                   <Allpersons 
                  
                   persons={this.state.persons}
                   clickrename={this.renamefun}
                   clickremove={this.removeperson}
                   />
        
      </div>
      
      );
      style.backgroundColor='red';


    }

   let styleclass=[];
   if(this.state.persons.length<=2){
     styleclass.push("bold");
   }

   if(this.state.persons.length<=1){
    styleclass.push("red");
  }
    styleclass=styleclass.join(" ");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>react</h1>
      <p>{this.state.c}</p>
     
     <p className={styleclass}>Here I am using the styleclass.</p>
      <button style={style} onClick={this.togglepersonview}>switch view</button>

       {showperson}

    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

### **2. BELOW IS THE CODE OF MY FUNCTION COMPONENT**

```
import React from 'react';
import Person from '../Person/Person';

const Allpersons=(props)=>props.persons.map((person,index)=>{
    return (
      <div>
          
         <Person name= {person.name}
        age = {person.age } 
        clickperson={()=>props.clickremove(index)}
        
        key={person.id}
        rename={(event)=>props.clickrename(event,person.id)}
        />
       </div>
    ) })
           
    export default Allpersons;
```

Comment: Please be more clear about your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React binding this to a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297676/react-binding-this-to-a-class-method)

Comment: `renamefun` and `removeperson` are class methods. They need to be told what `this` is when used from outside the class, either by using `clickrename={this.renamefun.bind(this)}` (or doing that in the class constructor) or by turning them into arrow functions.